# C/C++ Headers in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I installed IDE NetBeans for C/C++ development. I created C project with main.c and makefile generated netbeans. When i add test.h file in my project and try to compile it, i see that netbeans does not see this header file, and that I would not write it, even if there are errors anyway compilation is successful. How to connect a header file in netbeans?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

h-file is compiled only when it is included to c/cpp file:

```
#include "test.h"
```

Comment: h-file should be added to makefile as source file dependency, to ensure that every source file where it is included, is rebuilt when h-file is updated.